# Conatenate in C

Tags: c

I how Do I write a function to:

a) sum (and print) the length of the strings and to check the that that the sum of the strings is less than 70 before appending the two strings (null message appears if greater than 70)

b)  How do I use fgets in this circumstance?

c) I am also trying to print out the original two strings and the combined string.

This is what I have so far.. but am confused on how to proceeed???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char a[70], b[50];

   printf("Enter the first string\n");
   gets(a);

   printf("Enter the second string\n");
   gets(b);

   strcat(a,b);

   printf("String obtained on concatenation is %s\n",a);
```

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation about `fgets`?

Comment: strlen() will return the length of a string. eg int len = strlen(a);

Comment: @CharlieBurns: `strlen` returns a `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Do NOT use gets, use fgets instead:

```
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
fgets(b,sizeof(b),stdin);
```

2) `strlen()` in `string.h` will return the length of the given string.

> c) I am also trying to print out the original two strings and the combined string.

```
printf("Original string a : %s\n",a);
printf("Original string b : %s\n",b);

char *final = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1); //include stdlib.h for malloc()
strncpy(final,a,strlen(a)-1); //To skip copying new line character
strncat(final,b,strlen(b)-1);

printf("Combined string   : %s\n",final);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  How do I write a null message to be created if the string length is greater than 70?

Comment: Don't worry, fgets() will make sure that string length will never exceed 70 (the second parameter of the function : sizeof(a) = 70) ... any further user input after the 70th character will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main() {

 char buffer_a[BUFFERSIZE];
 char buffer_b[BUFFERSIZE];
 char *concat;

 printf("Enter the first string: \n");
 if(fgets(buffer_a, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)){
   char *p = strchr(buffer_a, '\n');
   if (p){
     *p = '\0';
   }
 }
 printf("Enter the second string: \n");
 if(fgets(buffer_b, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)){
   char *p = strchr(buffer_b, '\n');
   if (p){
     *p = '\0';
   }
 }

 int len_a = strlen(buffer_a);
 int len_b = strlen(buffer_b);
 int len_both = (len_a + len_b);

 printf("First string: %s", buffer_a);
 printf("Length of first string: %i\n", len_a);
 printf("Second string: %s", buffer_b);
 printf("Length of second string: %i\n", len_b);

 if(len_both < 70){
   concat = strcat(buffer_a,buffer_b);
   printf("Concatenated string: %s\n", concat);
 } else{
   printf("Length of combined strings > 70\n");
 }

 return 0;

}
```